# VS Code, Prettier and Flow not working nicely together - what am I missing?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using [the prettier-vscode](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode) extension to format my js code, but flow annotations are formatted in a weird way with lots of extra space:

```
const handleResponse = async function < T > ( // <-- should be function<T>(
  response,
  url: string,
  options: responseOptions = {}
): Promise < T | null > { // <-- should be Promise<T|null> {
                                        or Promise<T | null> {
```

I've looked around in all the places I could think of to see what config I need to change to get this working, but I can't find anywhere that seems to affect the spacing in te above case.

There's also some weirdness going on with multi-line ternary statements, but I don't think that's related to flow:

```
const WORKORDERS_BASE_URL =
  WORKORDERS_PORT === '80' ? // <-- I'd prefer if ? and : were on the next line
  `http://${WORKORDERS_HOST}` : // <-- on same indentation level as above - I want one more
  `http://${WORKORDERS_HOST}:${WORKORDERS_PORT}` // <-- same here, I want more indentation
```

The worst case of them all is this change, which happens when I format the document:

```
Promise<?T>
// becomes
Promise<<?T>
```

i.e. it actually breaks my code!

Where should I look for config that controls these things?